# Zend 2 Form Fieldset optional validation

Tags: php, forms, validation, zend-framework2, fieldset

I'm using a lot of nested Fieldset and was wondering if is it possible to set a required=false to a specific fieldset in order to not throw an error if there is any in it (and keep my form validating) ?

For example this is my UserFieldset :

```
-> {User Fieldset}
-----> Name
-----> Email address
-----> [other user fields...]
-----> {Avatar Fieldset}
----------> File
----------> [other avatar fields...]
-----> {other fieldsets...}
```

In my situation I want sometimes to force my user to add an avatar and sometimes not..

When I want to force there is no problem, my input file in my Avatar fieldset throws an error and blocks the validation process.

But when I want my user to simply register and eventually set its avatar, how can I do it ?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the elements that are validated using the `setValidationGroup()` method.

The [documentation states](http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.3/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html#validation-groups)

> Zend\Form provides a proxy method to the underlying InputFilter‘s setValidationGroup() method, allowing us to perform [validation] on only a subset of form elements

This could be done within the controller or perhaps a new factory; for example:

```
// Module.php
public function getFormElementConfig()
{
  return array(
      'factories' => array(
          'MyModule\Form\AvatarRegistrationFieldset' => function($fem) {

             $fieldset = new Form\AvatarFieldset();

             // Include the name of the elements you WANT to be validated
             $fieldset->setValidationGroup('foo', 'file');

             return $fieldset;
          }
      ),
  );
}
```

Comment: If I use setValidationGroup on my Avatar Fieldset (registration page), it will be no more validated and I will not be able to get data from it if my visitor eventually upload a file..

Comment: @VincentCaggiari You can keep the file element as an optional field and then *only on registration* include it within the validation group.